# How do I transform MongoDB "Row(oid=u'0123456789abcdef01234567')" to "0123456789abcdef01234567"?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm using Apache Spark with MongoDB all in Python.
Finally, I get an entry row from the DB, and from it I'm trying to get the _id column.
Unfortunately, I receive the ObjId in this format:

```
Row(oid=u'0123456789abcdef01234567')
```

In order to continue my work, I'm looking for some kind of transformation, that will make the object to look like this:

```
0123456789abcdef01234567
```

Sure, I can substring it, but a more elegant way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an object you have to use a dot to access its properties :

```
obj.oid
```

Then you have a unicode string, encoding it using 'utf-8' charset you get bytes, which you then have to decode to get your string object :

```
obj.oid.encode('utf-8').decode()
```

Example (python 3) :

```
>>> s = u'hello'                 # unicode
>>> s.encode('utf-8')            # to bytes
b'hello'
>>> s.encode('utf-8').decode()   # to string
'hello'
```

Example (python 2) :

```
>>> s = u'hello'                 # unicode
>>> s.encode('utf-8')            # to string
'hello'
```

Comment: Decoding a `unicode` object is the wrong way around. You *encode* a `unicode` to a `str`, and you *decode* a `str` to a `unicode`. Why you'd need to do either here I don't know.

Comment: En- and then decoding is also pretty nonsensical. I'd suggest you simply leave `obj.oid` as is, unless you explicitly need `bytes`/`str`.

Comment: @deceze the OP mentioned the need for a string object.

Comment: The confusing part here is also whether we're talking about a string (conceptually), or a `str` (Python 2) or a `str` (Python 3) or `bytes` (Python 3) or `unicode` (Python 2). Either way though, `.encode().decode()` ends up with exactly the same thing you had to begin with.

Comment: @deceze except you get an utf-8 string instead of unicode.

Comment: Your Python 3 example does nothing. Really. Type `u'hello'` into a console and the result is `'hello'`. It is already a `str` (equivalent to a `unicode` in Python 2). Your Python 2 example turns a `unicode` into a `str` (equivalent to `bytes` in Python 3). That makes more sense, but again it's debatable whether it's necessary here.